# Can't load custom checkout validator

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, validation

I've created a custom validator following [this official guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html) but I'm getting this error and the checkout page gets broken:

**"script error for: StoreLocator/js/view/store-code-validator"**

I have added in the `composer.json` module:

```
"require": {
    "magento/module-checkout": "100.1.*"
}
```

In `StoreLocator/view/frontend/web/js/model/validate-store-code.js`:

```
define(
    [],
    function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            /**
             * Validate store code before placing any order
             *
             * @returns {boolean}
             */
            validate: function() {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

In `StoreLocator/view/frontend/web/js/view/store-code-validator.js`:

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'StoreLocator_StoreLocator/js/model/validate-store-code'
],
function (Component, additionalValidators, validateStoreCode) {
    'use strict';
    additionalValidators.registerValidator(validateStoreCode);
    return Component.extend({});
});
```

Then I call the validation in `StoreLocator/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- Declare your validation. START -->
                                                                <item name="validate-store-code" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                                                                        StoreLocator_StoreLocator/js/view/store-code-validator
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <!-- Declare your validation. END -->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was at the XML. I didn't notice the call of the validation had empty spaces. Removed the spaces inside the  tag and it worked.

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">StoreLocator_StoreLocator/js/view/store-code-validator</item>
```